I'm not able to catch null pointer exception using error log object
I have created one custom object called ErrorLog__c and I have created some custom fields like:

Error_RecordIds__c
Error_Message__c
Error_Stack_Trace__c
JobId__c

My trigger code:
trigger BatchApexErrTrigger on BatchApexErrorEvent (after insert) {
        List<ErrorLog__c> errlist=new List<ErrorLog__c>();
        system.debug(Trigger.New);
        for(BatchApexErrorEvent evt:Trigger.New){
            system.debug(evt);
            ErrorLog__c err=new ErrorLog__c();
            err.Error_RecordIds__c=evt.JobScope;
            err.Error_Message__c=evt.Message;
            err.Error_Stack_Trace__c=evt.StackTrace;
            err.JobId__c=evt.AsyncApexJobId;
            errlist.add(err);
        }
        if(errList.size()>0)
            Insert errlist;
    }

my batch apex code:
public class LeadStatusUpdateBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful,Database.RaisesPlatformEvents {
        Integer recProcessed,recFailed;
        List<String> failedRecLinks= new List<String>();
        List<String> errMsg=new List<String>();
        String jobId;
        AsyncApexJob jobRec;
        Map<String, String> failedRecMap=new Map<String, String>();
        
        public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            String query='Select Id,Name,Status from Lead Where CreatedDate=LAST_N_DAYS:180 and status=\'Open - Not Contacted\'';
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }
        public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Lead> scope){
            system.debug(scope.size());
            system.debug(scope);
            for(Lead rec:scope){
                rec.Status='Closed - Not Converted';
            }
            //rec processed, rec failed, failed rec ids
           Database.SaveResult[] results=Database.update(scope,False);//update scope;
           for(Database.SaveResult result : results) {
               recProcessed+=1;
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    recFailed+=1;
                    //create url for failed records - domainurl + / + recordId
                    String recLink=url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() +'/'+result.getId();
                    failedRecLinks.add(recLink);
                    System.debug(' Error Message: ' + result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
                    failedRecMap.put(result.getId(),result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
                    /*
                    for(Database.Error error : result.getErrors()) {
                        System.debug(' Error Message: ' + error.getMessage());
                    }*/
                    //2 Colum- Error rec ID, err Msg
                }
            }
        }
        public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            System.debug('finish');
            jobId=bc.getJobId();
            jobRec=[Select Status, JobItemsProcessed,TotalJobItems,NumberOfErrors
                                from AsyncApexJob
                                Where Id=:bc.getJobId()];
            System.debug(jobRec);
            sendEmail();
        }
        //construct Email body
        public void sendEmail(){
            String toAddress='mirunalini0506@gmail.com';
            String subject='Job Status'+jobId;
            String body = 'Batch Job Status <br> Total Jobs : '+jobRec.jobItemsProcessed;
            body+='<br>Job Errors : '+jobRec.NumberOfErrors;
            body+='<br>Total Recc Processed : '+recProcessed;
            body+='<br>Total Failed Records : '+recFailed;
            for(String rec:failedRecLinks){
                body+='<br> '+rec;
            }
            EmailHelper.errEmail(body, subject, toAddress,failedRecMap);
        }
    }

In my Batch Apex code, I'm able to catch exceptions other than the null pointer exception and log them in the error log object. However, I'm unable to catch the null pointer exception in the error log object. What would be a workaround to address this issue?

in order to handle runtime errors, you have to use a try-catch block, refer to this article for more details: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_trycatch_example.htm

ok i will try it and keep you posted. thanks for the reply McCubo.

As you are using the Database.RaisesPlatformEvents I would expect the NPE to get through to your platform event trigger without any try/catch. When you look in your debug log, what line does the NPE originate from?
